# How do I set credentials for Symfony plugins?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-plugins

I have a backend with SfGuard, and I have plugins like sfGuard, which have modules. How do I change their security settings? they don't have folders in my backend app where I could put a security.yml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create module which you would like to secure, for example

```
/app/backend/modules/sfGuardRegister
```

After that you can secure the module with creating

```
/module_path/config/security.yml
```

and configure credentials.

I have not tryed that beheivour with security.yml, but I've rewroten the templates, actions, components. It should work.